# Is there any disadvantage in indexing text date eg. 2018-06-03 to increase date range query performance in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Consider the following db schema

```
 my_primary_id (text) primary index
 my_date (timestamp with timezone)
```

is there a way to index `my_date` such that I can have fast date range query?

My first thought is to make `my_date` a secondary index, however after thinking about it a bit, if each day I have 100k to 200k items, the cardinality of the `my_date` index will be similar to the number of rows I have.

since big index table -> slower query, I thought maybe I should store an extra column

```
`yyyy-mm-dd`
```

and index that instead?

Is there any disadvantage in that if I can guarantee that the date range query I do does not return more than 5% of my table size (preventing it using seq scan)?

My query pattern is the following

```
select * from my_table
where my_date >= my_start_date and my_date < my_end_date
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sounds like an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can index the date part of a timestamp by casting it to `date:

```
create index on the_table (my_date::date);
```

To make a query *use* that index, you need to use the same expression in your query:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_date::date >= date '2018-01-01'
  and my_date::date < date '2018-02-01';
```

I think an index on the timestamp column should be usable just as well, if you compare your column with a timestamp value:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_date >= timestamp '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
  and my_date < timestamp '2018-02-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect an index on the timestamp to work even with a date constant.  In any case, you could use `'2018-01-01'::timestamp`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: most probably supplying a `DATE` value would work - but I prefer not to rely on any implicit data type casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can partition the table by date. This speeds up querying tremendously if you have millions of records in date order and only need to work with a subset.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: For "millions" of rows, partitioning is rarely needed